# Pop-up "Project setup has stopped" cuando ejecuto mi aplicación

Tags: android, android-studio, avd

Intento seguir el curso de desarrollo androide de Udacity. Me las arreglé para hacer los primeros ejercicios y obtener una representación en el AVD. Consiste en crear una aplicación con una lista de juguete
. Pero hoy, a lo mejor, el AVD está bloqueado sobre una pagina "Project Setup", y, en el peor, hay un pop-up "Project setup has stopped".

[image: android project setup issue]

El output de logCat esta :

```
09-19 12:00:27.705 4564-4564/? D/AndroidRuntime: >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 2000 <<<<<<
09-19 12:00:27.707 4564-4564/? D/AndroidRuntime: CheckJNI is ON
09-19 12:00:27.720 4564-4564/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86_64
09-19 12:00:27.723 4564-4564/? D/ICU: No timezone override file found: /data/misc/zoneinfo/current/icu/icu_tzdata.dat
09-19 12:00:27.733 4564-4564/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
09-19 12:00:27.734 4564-4564/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
09-19 12:00:27.734 4564-4564/? I/Radio-JNI: register_android_hardware_Radio DONE
09-19 12:00:27.739 4564-4564/? D/AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
09-19 12:00:27.743 4564-4564/? I/art: System.exit called, status: 0
09-19 12:00:27.743 4564-4564/? I/AndroidRuntime: VM exiting with result code 0.
09-19 12:00:28.087 4583-4583/? D/AndroidRuntime: >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 2000 <<<<<<
09-19 12:00:28.088 4583-4583/? D/AndroidRuntime: CheckJNI is ON
09-19 12:00:28.107 4583-4583/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86_64
09-19 12:00:28.109 4583-4583/? D/ICU: No timezone override file found: /data/misc/zoneinfo/current/icu/icu_tzdata.dat
09-19 12:00:28.119 4583-4583/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
09-19 12:00:28.119 4583-4583/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
09-19 12:00:28.119 4583-4583/? I/Radio-JNI: register_android_hardware_Radio DONE
09-19 12:00:28.124 4583-4583/? D/AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
09-19 12:00:28.127 4583-4583/? I/art: System.exit called, status: 0
09-19 12:00:28.127 4583-4583/? I/AndroidRuntime: VM exiting with result code 0.
09-19 12:00:30.518 4596-4596/? D/AndroidRuntime: >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 2000 <<<<<<
09-19 12:00:30.520 4596-4596/? D/AndroidRuntime: CheckJNI is ON
09-19 12:00:30.535 4596-4596/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86_64
09-19 12:00:30.538 4596-4596/? D/ICU: No timezone override file found: /data/misc/zoneinfo/current/icu/icu_tzdata.dat
09-19 12:00:30.549 4596-4596/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
09-19 12:00:30.549 4596-4596/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
09-19 12:00:30.550 4596-4596/? I/Radio-JNI: register_android_hardware_Radio DONE
09-19 12:00:30.558 4596-4596/? D/AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.wm.Wm
09-19 12:00:30.559 4596-4596/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
09-19 12:00:30.563 4599-4599/? D/AndroidRuntime: >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 2000 <<<<<<
09-19 12:00:30.564 4599-4599/? D/AndroidRuntime: CheckJNI is ON
09-19 12:00:30.581 4599-4599/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86_64
09-19 12:00:30.583 4599-4599/? D/ICU: No timezone override file found: /data/misc/zoneinfo/current/icu/icu_tzdata.dat
09-19 12:00:30.593 4599-4599/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
09-19 12:00:30.593 4599-4599/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
09-19 12:00:30.593 4599-4599/? I/Radio-JNI: register_android_hardware_Radio DONE
09-19 12:00:30.598 4599-4599/? D/AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am

                                                 --------- beginning of system
09-19 12:00:30.600 1664-2037/system_process I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.example.favoritetoys/com.example.android.favoritetoys.MainActivity} from uid 2000 on display 0
09-19 12:00:30.605 4599-4599/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
09-19 12:00:30.610 4616-4616/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
09-19 12:00:30.610 4616-4616/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86_64
09-19 12:00:30.620 1664-2289/system_process I/ActivityManager: Start proc 4616:com.android.example.favoritetoys/u0a71 for activity com.android.example.favoritetoys/com.example.android.favoritetoys.MainActivity
09-19 12:00:30.663 1312-1909/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 8294400
09-19 12:00:30.756 2304-2400/com.android.launcher3 D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x71ec02a960c0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x71ec02be1280)
09-19 12:00:30.769 4616-4616/com.android.example.favoritetoys W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.android.example.favoritetoys-1/lib/x86_64
09-19 12:00:30.795 4616-4616/com.android.example.favoritetoys I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
09-19 12:00:31.445 1664-1689/system_process I/Choreographer: Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-19 12:00:31.446 1664-2038/system_process W/art: Long monitor contention with owner android.display (1689) at void com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator$1.doFrame(long)(WindowAnimator.java:138) waiters=0 in float com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.getCurrentAnimatorScale() for 646ms
09-19 12:00:32.443 1664-1689/system_process I/Choreographer: Skipped 59 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-19 12:00:32.444 1664-2038/system_process W/art: Long monitor contention with owner android.display (1689) at void com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator$1.doFrame(long)(WindowAnimator.java:138) waiters=0 in float com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.getCurrentAnimatorScale() for 998ms
09-19 12:00:33.443 1664-2038/system_process W/art: Long monitor contention with owner android.display (1689) at void com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator$1.doFrame(long)(WindowAnimator.java:138) waiters=0 in float com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.getCurrentAnimatorScale() for 998ms
09-19 12:00:33.445 1664-1689/system_process I/Choreographer: Skipped 59 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-19 12:00:33.471 4616-4616/com.android.example.favoritetoys W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
09-19 12:00:34.442 1664-2320/system_process W/art: Long monitor contention with owner android.display (1689) at void com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator$1.doFrame(long)(WindowAnimator.java:138) waiters=0 in float com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.getCurrentAnimatorScale() for 935ms
09-19 12:00:34.453 1312-1910/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property

                                                 [ 09-19 12:00:34.456  4616: 4616 D/         ]
                                                 HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x71ec04895600, tid 4616


                                                 [ 09-19 12:00:34.457  4616: 4616 W/         ]
                                                 Unrecognized GLES max version string in extensions: ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 

                                                 [ 09-19 12:00:35.499  4616: 4633 D/         ]
                                                 HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x71ec0721c7e0, tid 4633


                                                 [ 09-19 12:00:35.505  4616: 4633 W/         ]
                                                 Unrecognized GLES max version string in extensions: ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 
09-19 12:00:35.505 4616-4633/com.android.example.favoritetoys I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
09-19 12:00:35.505 4616-4633/com.android.example.favoritetoys D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
09-19 12:00:35.505 4616-4633/com.android.example.favoritetoys W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
09-19 12:00:35.505 4616-4633/com.android.example.favoritetoys D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
09-19 12:00:35.523 4616-4633/com.android.example.favoritetoys D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0x71ec07236d20: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
09-19 12:00:35.541 4616-4633/com.android.example.favoritetoys D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x71ec07236d20: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x71ec0720c840)
09-19 12:00:35.578 4616-4616/com.android.example.favoritetoys W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
09-19 12:00:35.587 4616-4633/com.android.example.favoritetoys D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x71ec07236d20: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x71ec0720c840)
09-19 12:00:35.666 1664-1689/system_process I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.android.example.favoritetoys/com.example.android.favoritetoys.MainActivity: +5s62ms
09-19 12:00:35.675 1664-2271/system_process I/WindowManager: Destroying surface Surface(name=com.android.launcher3/com.android.launcher3.Launcher) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:2014 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:881 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.destroyOrSaveSurface:2073 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.destroySurfaces:363 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.notifyAppStopped:389 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.notifyAppStopped:4456 com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.activityStoppedLocked:1252 com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.activityStopped:6903 
09-19 12:00:35.853 1664-1689/system_process I/WindowManager: Destroying surface Surface(name=Starting com.android.example.favoritetoys) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:2014 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:881 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.destroyOrSaveSurface:2073 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.destroySurfaces:363 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.finishExit:565 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.stepAnimationLocked:491 com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.updateWindowsLocked:303 com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.animateLocked:704
```

Funcionan las consultas con Google.

Comment: Hey Marine1 El uso del LogCat es importante en Android, la causa pueden ser demasiadas, te sugiero agregues más datos a tu pregunta. Revisa si puedes abrir el Chrome en el AVD para comprobar también tienes conexión a internet.

Comment: @Jorgesys
¡Oído! Sí, tengo la conexión a Internet.